# How to determine which items are on the critical path in GAMS?

Tags: linear-programming, gams-math

This is my current code on GAMS.  Yes, I know it can be more concise, but bear with me here:

```
set activity /a*q/;

parameter duration (activity) "in days"
/a 15, b 4, c 5, d 10, e 4, f 15, g 15, h 5, i 5, j 10, k 4, l 3, m 4, n 20, o 5,
p 2, q 2/;

alias (activity, x, y);

set prec(x,y) "Precedence Order"

/A.(B,C,D)
(B,C,D).E
E.(F,G,H)
F.N
G.(K,I) 
H.I
K.M
I.J
J.L
L.M
M.N
N.O
O.P
P.Q/            ;

Free Variable
T Completion Time; 

Nonnegative Variables
A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q;

equations
t_A, t_B, t_C, t_D, t_E, t_F, t_G, t_H, t_I, t_J, t_K, t_L, t_M, t_N, t_O, t_P,
t_Q, s_AB, s_AC, s_AD, s_BE, s_CE, s_DE, s_EF, s_EG, s_EH, s_FN, s_GK, s_GI,
s_HI, s_KM, s_IJ, s_JL, s_LM, s_MN, s_NO, s_OP, s_PQ;

t_A.. T =G= A + 15;
t_B.. T =G= B + 4;
t_C.. T =G= C + 5;
t_D.. T =G= D + 10;
t_E.. T =G= E + 4;
t_F.. T =G= F + 15;
t_G.. T =G= G + 15;
t_H.. T =G= H + 5;
t_I.. T =G= I + 5;
t_J.. T =G= J + 10;
t_K.. T =G= K + 4;
t_L.. T =G= L + 3;
t_M.. T =G= M + 4;
t_N.. T =G= N + 20;
t_O.. T =G= O + 5;
t_P.. T =G= P + 2;
t_Q.. T =G= Q + 10;

s_AB.. A + 15 =L= B;
s_AC.. A + 15 =L= C;
s_AD.. A + 15 =L= D;
s_BE.. B + 4 =L= E;
s_CE.. C + 5 =L= E;
s_DE.. D + 10 =L= E;
s_EF.. E + 4 =L= F;
s_EG.. E + 4 =L= G;
s_EH.. E + 4 =L= H;
s_FN.. F + 15 =L= N;
s_GK.. G + 15 =L= K;
s_GI.. G + 15 =L= I;
s_HI.. H + 5 =L= I;
s_KM.. K + 4 =L= M;
s_IJ.. I + 5 =L= J;
s_JL.. J + 10 =L= L;
s_LM.. L + 3 =L= M;
s_MN.. M + 4 =L= N;
s_NO.. N + 20 =L= O;
s_OP.. O + 5 =L= P;
s_PQ.. P + 2 =L= Q;

model thesis /all/;
solve thesis using lp minimizing t;
display t.l;
```

This code gives me a ton of details, such as what days I should start each activity.  However, it doesn't tell me (as far as I can see), which activities are on the critical path.  How can I determine this using GAMS?

Answer (score 0):

A dependency lies on the critical path if the marginal on the dependency equation (s_AB etc. in your formulation) is -1. You can check this in the listing (.lst) file or by using the code below:

```
set activity /a*q/;

parameter duration (activity) "in days"
/a 15, b 4, c 5, d 10, e 4, f 15, g 15, h 5, i 5, j 10, k 4, l 3, m 4, n 20, o 5,
p 2, q 2/;

alias (activity, x, y);

set prec(x,y) "dependency Order"

/A.(B,C,D)
(B,C,D).E
E.(F,G,H)
F.N
G.(K,I) 
H.I
K.M
I.J
J.L
L.M
M.N
N.O
O.P
P.Q/;

Free Variable
T Completion Time; 

Nonnegative Variables
start(x);

equations
t_bound(x)
dependency(x,y);

t_bound(x).. T =G= start(x) + duration(x);

dependency(x,y)$prec(x,y).. start(x) + duration(x) =l= start(y);

model thesis /all/;
solve thesis using lp minimizing t;

set criticalpath(x,y);
criticalpath(x,y) = 1$(dependency.M(x,y) < 0);

display t.l, criticalpath;
```